# Changing Order of Integration in x,y,z plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$
\int_{0}^{9}\int_{0}^{3}\int_{2y}^{6} \frac{2\cos x^2}{3\sqrt{z}}\,dx\,dy\,dz
$$

Evaluate the integral by changing order of integration.

I can do this over double integral just fine. But this question is giving me quite a bit of trouble.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can do this in the x,y plane just fine"?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the region of integration? (By which i mean the limits and not $\frac{2\cos x^2}{3\sqrt{z}}$)

Comment: Can you evaluate that integral just fine? The anti-derivative of $\cos x^2$ is not $\sin x^2$ or $\frac{\sin x^2}{2x}$ or any other elementary function for that matter. That is why they want you to interchange the order of integration.

Comment: Hint: The integrand is separable, i.e., of the form $f(x,y)g(z)$. So this is actually just the matter of how to compute a double integral on a $(x,y)$ domain.

Answer (score 3):

So you have $\frac{2\cos x^2}{3\sqrt z}$ integrated over the domain $z\in [0,9], y\in[0,3], x\in [2y, 6]$

That's also the domain $z\in [0,9], x\in[0,6], y\in[0,x/2]$ by swapping the x and y integration order.  Note also that since the domain of z is independent of those of x and y, and because the term can be separated, it can be integrated separately.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^9\int_0^6\int_0^{x/2}\frac{2\cos x^2}{3\sqrt z}\operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}z & = \int_0^9\int_0^6\frac{x\cos x^2}{3\sqrt z}\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}z
\\ &= \frac 1 3 \int_0^9 \frac 1 {\sqrt z}\operatorname{d}z \cdot \int_0^6 x\cos x^2 \operatorname{d}x
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: should there be a $3$ in the denominator?

Comment: @illysial Ah, yes, indeed there should.  Thank you.  (Updated)

Comment: so the answer is 2 x (sin(36)/2) or just sin(36)

Comment: Thanks. This makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the limits of integration will yield:

$$\int_0^9\int_0^6\int_0^\frac{x}{2} \frac{2 \cos x^2}{3 \sqrt{z}} dy \ dx \ dz$$

After integrating with respect to $y$ we will have: $$\int_0^9 \int_0^6\frac{2 x \cos x^2}{6 \sqrt{z}} \ dx \ dz.$$